# Handling PromisesRejections inside Express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, exception, promise

I would like to handle unhandled Promises Rejections using a middleware function, because I have to know the Request and Response objects of the request.

I have written the following code, but when the code throws an unhandled Promise, it seems that the middleware / process.on function are not called.

So, my question is: is it possible to handle Promises Rejections with a middleware or (alternatively) get the Request / Response objects of the request causing error in case of Unhandled Exceptions?

I tried making the middleware as the first middleware of my app, but with no results: it does not get called at all.

```js
app.use ( ( err: Error, req: ILRequest, res: ILResponse, next: ILNextFunction ) =>
    {
        console.log ( "\n\n***** OUTSIDE ERR: ", err );

        process.on ( 'unhandledRejection', ( error: any ) =>
        {
            console.log ( "\n\n------ ERROR " );
        } );
    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Middleware is only called on HTTP requests. If you want to try `process.on('unhandledRejection')` put it on "top level" - there should be only one. However, to get any of those values into a http response, you'd have to store a global error (or array of errors) and have another HTTP request check the error array. Or watch your server logs.

You can write your middleware to handle the rejected promises, calling `next` with the appropriate values. Something like:

```
app.use( (err, req, res, next) => {
  promiseThing
  .then( (good) => {
    // do something with good value
    next()
  })
  .catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
  // could be written shorter as .catch(next)
})
```

Comment: What I am trying to do, is actually have a **default** fallback for unhandled promises, the ones that usually crashes Express applications if not handled correctly in the code.

Thank you for your reply, but if I understand it correctly, it is not what I am looking for, since it is "local" to a single promise.

My software is only handling HTTP requests so it is the perfect scenario.

Comment: That sounds interesting, I'm not sure it is possible and will watch for other answers. You might try a piece of middleware like ```app.use( async function errorCatcher(err,req,res,next) {
    try{
      next()
    } catch (e) {
      next(e)
    }
}``` which might chain back if there is an unexpected error. I have not used Express for a while so am not sure how to best handle it in your scenario.

Comment: The middleware you suggested is real black magic to me (why having an async function inside a middleware doing nothing ...) but it does not work. Tested as the first middleware and also as the last one, with no success.
Thank you anyway for your support.

Comment: The intent was to have something catch any error down the chain. You  probably saw this link: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html, and here's a blog as well https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/2854ef613751563a3b506fabce4501fd. That blog might do it? Anyway, good look, I'm too far removed from Express to help more!